# How to change JFrame header color?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to change `JFrame Header color`, it's stable with white color by default but i need to change it to black like the body background. [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can't change it.

What you can do is to create window without that header and custom paint it.

Comment: How to make it?